# Merging two columns in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following `DataFrame`:

```
      A     B
0 -10.0   NaN
1   NaN  20.0
2 -30.0   NaN
```

I want to merge columns `A` and `B`, filling the `NaN` cells in column `A` with the values from column `B` and then drop column `B`, resulting in a `DataFrame` like this:

```
     A
0 -10.0
1  20.0
2 -30.0
```

I have managed to solve this problem by using the `iterrows()` function.

Complete code example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

example_data = [[-10, np.NaN], [np.NaN, 20], [-30, np.NaN]]

example_df = pd.DataFrame(example_data, columns = ['A', 'B'])

for index, row in example_df.iterrows():
    if pd.isnull(row['A']):
        row['A'] = row['B']

example_df = example_df.drop(columns = ['B'])        

example_df
```

This seems to work fine, but I find this information in [the documentation for `iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

> You should **never modify** something you are iterating over.

So it seems like I'm doing it wrong.

What would be a better/recommended approach for achieving the same result?

Comment: `iterrows` is damn slow, always use `apply` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = df['A'].fillna(df['B']).to_frame()
#alternative
#df = df['A'].combine_first(df['B']).to_frame()
print (df)
      A
0 -10.0
1  20.0
2 -30.0
```

If more columns and need first non missing values per rows use back filling missing values with select first column by one element list for one column `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, [0]]
print (df)
      A
0 -10.0
1  20.0
2 -30.0
```

Comment: I just learned I have been doing this in two lines rather than 1.